# Why is upvoting comments possible when I ran out of upvotes for questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, comments, voting

Yesterday it happened that I ran out of upvotes (for questions and answers). But I was able to upvote two (or more) interesting comments.

I thought upvoting a comment reduce the number of free question upvotes.
Can someone explain or is this a bug?

(I hope the tags are right so?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are simply different, so this is not a bug. You have one quota of comment votes, and a different quota of question votes. Also, voting on comments is less "serious" -- it doesn't influence reputation, and one cannot downvote -- than voting on questions/answers.

See e.g. ['Daily vote limit reached' only for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96147/daily-vote-limit-reached-only-for-comments)